# GridSearchCV parameters don't improve classification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, xgboost, grid-search

I have a target dataset that I divide into 5 non-overlapping folds. 
At each iteration (total iterations == 5) I use 1 fold (let's call it `fold_for_tuning`) to do parameter tuning, and I use 4 folds for testing.

The reason for this is that I want to do domain adaptation, and before tuning, I fit the source data to the classifier, and I am tuning using small subset of target data).

I call GridSearchCV and fit `fold_for_tuning`, and also I pass a bunch of parameters that I want to tune:

```
param_test1 = {
            'max_depth': [5, 7],
            'min_child_weight': [0.5, 1, 2],
            'gamma': [0.1, 1],
            'subsample': [0.6, 0.7],
            'colsample_bytree': [0.6, 0.7],
            'reg_alpha': [0.01, 0.1]
        }

gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifierXGB,
                                param_grid=param_test1,
                                scoring='accuracy',
                                n_jobs=4, iid=False, cv=2)

gsearch.fit(fold_for_tuning_data, fold_for_tuning_labels)
```

After each iteration, I get `gsearch.best_params_`, and I set them into `classifierXGB`(because they should give better prediction, in my understanding).
Then, when I call 
`test_y_predicted = classifierXGB.predict(4_unseen_folds)`
I get not improvement:

```
prediction before tuning:
acc: 0.690658872245
auc: 0.700764301397
f1: 0.679211922203
prediction after tuning:
acc: 0.691382460414
auc: 0.701595887248
f1: 0.680132554837
```

**But if I call** `gsearch.predict(4_unseen_folds)`
**I get MUCH BETTER performance:**

```
prediction grid search :
acc: 0.933313032887
auc: 0.930058979926
f1: 0.920623414281
```

**So I am confused: what is happening inside grid search? Shouldn't it be optimizing only the parameters that I pass in `param_grid`? If so, then why setting the very same parameters in `classifierXGB` doesn't result into better performance?**

Comment: What do you call `iteration` ? It's not clear

Comment: Can you show a [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including what you do following `gsearch.fit` please?

Answer (score 1):

Your `gsearch.predict(...)` call **is** the prediction of the best classifier.

I'm not sure what's happening in the background of `ClassifierXGB`, but if you create a **new** `classifierXGB`:

```
classifierXGB = ClassifierXGB(**gsearch.best_params_)`
```

and **then** call `classifierXGB.predict(4_unseen_folds)` you should see something similar to `gsearch.predict(4_unseen_folds)`.

It might be that applying changes to `classifierXGB` after the fact doesn't do what you expect. Creating a new instance of `ClassifierXGB` should help.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have set your parameters to your `classifierXGB`, you need **to fit it** on the whole train data, **and then**, use it to predict things

The grid search found the "right" parameters, you gave them to your classifier for it to learn efficiently, but you did not gave him the actual trees/weights of the model. It is still an empty shell.